# Coffeescript Common files module

Tags: module, coffeescript

I have a few common files like logger, stopwatch, metrics, etc. Now, I would like to add all of them in 1 common.coffee and place this files in a common folder under lib.

```
lib/common/logger.coffee
lib/common/metrics.coffee
lib/common/stopwatch.coffee
lib/common.coffee
```

Now, when I have to use these files. I just do a

```
require( 'lib/common' )
```

and should be able to call the logger class

like `logger.info`, etc in the lib files.

How to go about doing it ? Below is the common.coffee but it requires me to say "Common.logger" whenever I have to use it. I dont want the Common prefix

```
nconf = require('nconf')

environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

nconf.file 'environment', "config/#{environment}.json"
nconf.file 'default', 'config/default.json'

module.exports = {
  logger: require('lib/common/logger')
  metrics: require('lib/common/metrics') nconf
  stopwatch: require('lib/common/stop_watch')
}
```

Also, how can I make a module of the common folder so that I can just use npm to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use destructuring assignments on your require call.

```
{logger, metrics, stopwatch} = require("lib/common")
```

another way would be to use a build tool like grunt.js and call a concatination task before building the final deployment articfact.